# Using one calibration matrix to render different objects's images?

Tags: python, scripting, camera

I have a deep learning project that I need to generate 1500 synthetic images by Blender for 15 classes' objects with 100 for each of them. My purpose is to make my synthetic images as similar as possible to the real objects' images.

What I think is to use camera calibration to find the real world's camera matrix, then set the camera matrix in Blender.

Since I am quite new to Blender, my questions are:

1. Once I set up the camera's matrix, can it be used for all my objects in Blender? I took photos of the objects in the real world in the way that keep the camera being fixed, no matter the angle or its position. Then I took photos for each of the objects and I tried to keep them stay in the same position. But there much be some slight difference in the position and also due to their shapes are not same. Or do I need to find each one's camera matrix in the real world then apply in Blender?

If it works, could you tell me what is the Python script to set up the camera matrix in Blender?

Thanks.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=camera%20matrix

Comment: Yes, thanks. I also found them. But there seems no answer to my second question.

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask multiple questions but as separate posts. I suggest editing your post using the [edit] link below it to reduce it to one question and ask the other questions separately. Thanks.